# Same product different store views in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, product, store-view

Let's describe the "problem" a little more. I have an e-shop with 15 products at the moment, i want those products to appear also in the English store view, what i want to ask is that, i have to add the product again with english description and everything else or there is a shorter way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a product edit page in the admin section, you will have a drop down that allows you to edit the content of description (and other values) through each view.

There is a default view which sets the standard value which you can change to other websites and other store views and update on each website.

Comment: you mean the the store view dropdown menu?

Comment: Thats correct, select the view you want to change a value for, and update the relevant values i.e. description, short description etc. When you save (clear cache if necessary) this will only reflect on that store view or website.

Comment: So i don't need to add the product again on a different store view, just select the store view that i want and translate the description and anything else and that's it, right?

Comment: I have tried just now, and it works fine. I will mark the answer as solution.